# Download osm data in many languages

Tags: openstreetmap, internationalization

Does the OSM provide data for street names in different languages? E.g. Spanish and English. If yes, how can I download them?

Comment: If users have saved names with different languages they are all included in the data. Look at the name:[language_code] tags http://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/relation/2555133

Comment: ... or see the OSM wiki about http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Multilingual_names and http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_internationalization for more hints.

Answer (score 1):

When you are downloading data from OSM, like [polygon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241814/how-to-download-polygon-files-like-lake-or-municipal-borders-from-openstreetma/241819#241819) or [roads](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246068/is-there-a-way-to-download-and-edit-an-osm-file-in-qgis/246069#246069), you will have the "names" column written in the common language.
However, it is the most likely that you will need to change the encoding of the layer, otherwise it will look like this.

[image]

In order of preventing this, you need to go to the layer proprietors.

[image]

At the proprietors go to "General" and change the encoding. The "UTF-8" is the most likely be a good choice and the caption will be displayed as they are supposed to be.

[image]