# Downloading polygon files, like lake or municipal borders, from OpenStreetMap in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I have a project that requires the polygon files of a large lake in the United States.

I found Lake Michigan in QGIS with the [osmSearch plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/osmSearch/).

[image]

I did not find a way to download this data as a vector or raster file.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Within the US, a lot of GIS data is available for free from the US Geological Survey. Access it here: https://viewer.nationalmap.gov/basic/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have spent few hours and find a way to download a data from OSM into Qgis:

1) You need to have the "OSM place search" plugin[image]

2)You need to add this plugin in the panel [image]

3)Search the item you need in the search bar [image]

4) After you double click one the result it will appear [image]

5)Add the item as a layer into your map [image]

6)make sure to use the right CRS  [image]

7) Export the new layer as a file  [image]

If you cannot find this plugin you need to go to the "setting" in the plugin and enable the experimental plugin setting [image]

Comment: About step 6 "make sure to use the right CRS". 
Have QGIS version 3.4.10-Madeira. The only projection actually working is EPSG:3857 (web mercator). Nor sure if it is a bug but when projecting in any other EPSG my new created scratch layer geometry is empty.

Answer (score 6):

**Using overpass-turbo:**

1. Go to [overpass-turbo.eu](https://overpass-turbo.eu/)
2. Move the map to the place you're looking for
3. Type your search query: `relation["name"="Lake Michigan"]({{bbox}});`
4. Export as e.g. GeoJSON

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [OSMInfo QGIS plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/osminfo/)

[image]

Small [description](https://nextgis.com/blog/osminfo/) and [video](https://youtu.be/30ZT5hdjhuI).

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to use one of this two similar plugins: OSMDownloader InaSAFE.
This two plugin are enabling to download a line and polygon layers form relatively small area. This two plugins are useful in an urban area and they provide an accurate line layer of street or polygon layer of buildings.

Take for example the city of New York: by clicking the download bottom this window will open. [image]
Now you need to mark your area of interest. [image]
Once finishing this step you will have a layer of streets that you can work with.[image]