# Converting OpenStreetMap data to shapefile using OGR?

Tags: shapefile, gdal, openstreetmap, ogr

How would I reliably convert OSM-data (.osm, .kml, .gpx or .geojson) to .shp?
ogr2ogr seems have issues:

**geojson:**

```
$ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" destination_data.shp export.geojson   
ERROR 6: Can't create field alt_name31 in Shape DBF file. Maximum record length reached.    
Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'alt_name:fa' to 'alt_name31'
```

**kml, gpx:**

```
$ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" destination_data.shp export.kml  -lco ENCODING=UTF-8   
Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'Description' to 'Descriptio'   
Warning 1: Value '...' of field Descriptio has been truncated to 254 characters.
```

And encoding is off.

Comment: You are hitting inherent limits in the shapefile format. What do you want to throw away ? Would it be better to just download a pre-shapefile'd version: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Shapefiles ?

Comment: Ah, I see from your other question that you already had that link. Its still just an inherent limit of the shapefile format though.

Comment: If you are looking for polygons Shapefile from OSM like lake or nature reserves have a look in this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241814/how-to-download-polygon-files-like-lake-or-municipal-borders-from-openstreetma).

Answer (score 1):

ESRI Shapefile's field name can be up to certain characters limitation. supposed if you try to convert from GeoJSON to Shapefile then try to change your geoJSON property "alt_name31" to "altnam" And try it.

But if you have `*.osm` file then bellow code may be easily doing your job.

```
 $ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" destination_data.shp export.osm multipolygons
```

The OSM driver will categorize features into 5 layers: points, lines, multilinestrings, multipolygons, and other_relations. So you have to pass anyone at the end of the command which you desire.