# How to find the location of parking areas in OSM with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I am making a small size map with QGIS.
I need to mark the parking areas in three streets in Philadelphia: 54th street, Residential street and Berks street.

I was wondering, is there a way to get the locations of these parking areas?

Maybe it can be download in a [similar way](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241814/how-to-download-polygon-files-like-lake-or-municipal-borders-from-openstreetma) to the one that is used to download street and buildings layer from 
[OSM](http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=18/39.98198/-75.23054)?

I could not find this data in the OSM plugins that I am using in QGIS: `OSMDownloader` and `osmSearch`.

If it is of any help, here is the map area and the streets are marked with arrows.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use overpass-turbo:

https://overpass-turbo.eu/#

Code:

```
<osm-script output="json" timeout="200"> 
 <id-query {{nominatimArea:Philadelphia}} into="area"/> 
 <union>
      <query type="node">
           <has-kv k="amenity" v="parking"/> 
           <area-query from="area"/>
      </query>
      <query type="way">
           <has-kv k="amenity" v="parking"/> 
           <area-query from="area"/>
      </query>
      <query type="relation">
           <has-kv k="amenity" v="parking"/> 
           <area-query from="area"/>
      </query>
 </union>
 <union>
      <item />
      <recurse type="down"/>
 </union>
 <print mode="body" />
</osm-script>
```

Then zoom to data, and download as GeoJSON.