# Choosing a Projected CRS in Order of Making a 3D Polygon Display in QGIS 3.4.1

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, 3d

I have been followed the [Instructions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/302202/making-a-3d-polygon-with-3d-view-in-qgis-3-4) explained how to make 3D polygons.

I have downloaded some random polygons from [OSM](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246068/is-there-a-way-to-download-and-edit-an-osm-file-in-qgis) and defined the 'Extrusion' with the expression rand (5, 40).

[image]

Then, I select the "3D View" function.

[image]

At this point I got an error message that telling me that my CRS are not "projected CRS".

[image]

I used in this project "WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator" CRS, which I do not know to which CRS I should change them into. I changed the measurement units to degrees, it did not help.

[image]

What is the correct CRS?
Is there are anything more need to be done in order of making a 3D map from a random polygon that is not listed in the steps I have listed?

Comment: The CRS you are using is NOT a projected CRS, in fact it is a geographical CRS. Depending on where your data is located, project your data to a UTM projection and then run again the 3D. Check here http://www.jaworski.ca/utmzones.htm

Comment: UTM zones are not related to time zones. If you open the link in my previous post, you can identify in which zone your data is located. Say it is in the UTM22 zone (just an example). Then you have to check if they are located in the northern hemisphere or in the southern. So, if your data are in the northern hemisphere, your final projection will be UTM22N. Here is a list of all the CRS available http://spatialreference.org/. Otherwise you can use this site https://www.latlong.net/lat-long-utm.html to check the UTM zone (just prompt the coordinates of a point in your data)

Comment: There is a not a generic UTM projection. You have to select the right one that fix with your data location

Comment: I tried, but QGIS crashed. My new laptop will arrive soon and I will try it once more. Thanks.

Comment: Did the software crash during the saving of the projected data or with the 3D view?

Comment: With the 3D view

Comment: You can try to publish the data with http://qgis4dummies.wikidot.com/qgis2threejs to see if they are properly working in the meantime