# Selecting Specific Entities to Style Separately from the Same Layer in QGIS 3.2.4

Tags: qgis, layers, style

I downloaded the roads of Rome from [OSM](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246068/is-there-a-way-to-download-and-edit-an-osm-file-in-qgis) and save them as a single Shapefile.

To style specific entities from the "highway" column I categorized this column in the layer styling panel.

Now I got all the 28 highway types, each in a different color.

[image]

However, I want to change the style for only one entities and to keep all the other in a different style.

To do it manually will take a lot of time, so I am looking for a faster way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem lies in the values choosing.

Instead of classify all the values as one I click the plus sign. Now I have all the types of highways in one style.

[image]

Now, for example I want to sort out and change the style only for the "path" highways.
In the layer styling panel I write the "path" as  knew classified value.

[image]

Know I am able to change the style of all of the road excerpt from the selected value, and to change the selected value apart form all the other values.